# Sent an email from Outlook 2010 - it was not sent and is not in sent folder, where could it be?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I always thought that the advantage of using desktop email client is that your emails are saved even if network issues occur. Clearly wrong.

I wrote a rather long email yesterday. I have sent it and went to sleep. Today, none of my colleagues knew what I'm talking about. So I checked and the email is not in the Sent, nor is it in Concepts. It's gone.

So the question I have is if it could be somewhere else. Is there any temp folder where Outlook stores the emails? Anything that would save me from having to write it again?

Comment: Check the Outbox. Not the same as the Sent folder.

Comment: Using the Instant search box to search in the entire mailbox to see if the message can be found.

Answer (score 1):

You have to come across list of folders available in your Outlook app. There should be a folder for outgoing emails (they're scheduled for the delivery but not sent yet, due the big size, or network issue, or etc.). Actual name of the folder may vary depending on the localization and app version, and generally the folder is at the bottom of the folders list or so. You should find something like

```
> Outbox [1]
```

As soon as your email is longy, just give your PC enough time to deliver the message to nearest email relay so it will be moved to `Sent` folder then. If you don't see the message in the Outbox, well, it's a glitch, bad luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was already aware of outbox folder and the email wasn't there either. Maybe this will help somebody else though.